# Altarelli-Parisi Splitting Function $P_{qq}(z)$ vanishing integral if and only if quark flavour sum rules and equivalence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics, protons

Question 1: I believe both questions are in the context of Deep Inelastic Scattering. I've been given the expression for $F_{2}^{ep}(x)=(\frac{2}{3})^2[u(x)+\bar{u}(x)]
+(\frac{1}{3})^2[d(x) + \bar{d}(x)+s(x) + \bar{s}(x)]$ and 
 $F_{2}^{en}(x)=(\frac{2}{3})^2[d(x)+\bar{d}(x)]
+(\frac{1}{3})^2[u(x) + \bar{u}(x)+s(x) + \bar{s}(x)]$
in the naive parton model where the terms u, d, s and their barred versions are parton densities in a proton.

I've been told to show that the integral of the Altarelli-Parisi splitting function $P_{qq}(z)$ over z vanishing

$\int^1_0P_{qq}(z)dz=0$ is equivalent to the quark flavour sum rules

$\int_0^1[u(x,Q^2)-\bar{u}(x,Q^2)] dx=2$,  $\int_0^1[d(x,Q^2)-\bar{d}(x,Q^2)] dx=1$,

$\int_0^1[s(x,Q^2)-\bar{s}(x,Q^2)] dx=0$ being preserved as Q^2 varies.

I was looking through my notes and found these which may be useful $P_{qq}(z)=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1+z^2}{1-z}\right)_{+}$,
$P_{qg}(z)=\frac{1}{2}[z^2+(1-z)^2]$ with momentum conservation $\int^1_0[2fP{qg}(z)+P{gg}(z)]dz=0$; I'm still unsure on what I should do.

Question 2

I need to show A-P Splitting Function$P_{qq}(z)=\frac{4}{3}\frac{1+z^2}{(1-z)_{+}}+2\delta(1-z)$ can be rewritten as $P_{qq}(z)=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1+z^2}{1-z}\right)_+$. I've definitions of this + integral notation but I remain unsure to how to tackle it.

Comment: You should include the definition of the $+$-distribution because there are several in the literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer question 2.  Let $f$ be a smooth test function,

$$\int_0^1 \frac{4}{3}\frac{1+z^2}{(1-z)_+}f(z) + 2 \delta(1-z) f(z) dz = \int_0^1 \frac{4}{3}\frac{(1+z^2)f(z) - 2f(1)}{(1-z)} + 2 \delta(1-z)f(z) dz $$
using the definition of a $+$-distribution.  Continuing after some simplification; one tries to force the two bits together by cleverly adding a factor,
$$ 2f(1) + \int_0^1 \frac{4}{3}\frac{(1+z^2)f(z) - 2f(1)}{(1-z)}  dz =\int_0^1 \frac{4}{3}\frac{(1+z^2)f(z) - 2f(1)}{(1-z)}  + \frac{4}{3} (z+1) f(1)dz  $$
You will need to check that I have got the factors right here and not just fudged it!  Anyway combining the terms,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{4}{3} \frac{z^2+1}{1-z} (f(z)-f(1)) dz = \int_0^1 \frac{4}{3}\left[ \frac{1+z^2}{1-z}\right]_+ f(z) dz$$
again by the definition of the $+$-distribution.

(Hopefully I will have time to answer question 1 later!)

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about this!  If you look [here](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2014-03-31/qcdgrad_rojo_oxford_tt14_5_dis_pdf_19197.pdf) then on page 23 you can see how the non-singlet DGLAP equation will solve part 1 for you. (I'm not the author or anything, I just don't want to copy the LaTeX out.)